# Xcode: Saving randomly displayed entry/text from a database to a file

Tags: xcode

I'm new to coding. I have a database that I am able to display random data from when a button is pressed. But I am having trouble figuring out how to then save that output to a file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to export your random data generator as an app, first archive the app file:

**XCode -> Product -> Archive**

In the next window:

**Choose Export -> AdHoc**

and you should have your .ipa file.